# R: iterative outliers detection

Tags: r, outliers

I have a data frame (df) as follows:

```
V V1 V2 V3
1  A  B  32
1  A  C  33
1  A  E  43 
1  A  F  22
1  A  T  53 
1  A  N  54
1  C  T  44 
1  C  G  11
1  C  N  31
1  C  D  53
1  C  U  75
1  A  T  53 
1  A  N  54
2  C  T  42 
2  C  G  14
2  C  N  35
2  C  D  23
2  C  U  56
```

What want to do I to get the outliers for each combination of (V,V1) and this is to easy to achieve with the code I have.

```
d <- as.data.table(df)

# Add a column to keep track of row numbers
d[, c('row'):= list(seq_len(nrow(d)))]

# For each group (combination of V and V1), perform the outlier test
outliers <- d[, chisq.out.test(V3), list(V, V1)]
```

The main problem is that this function would return for each combination of (`V,V1`) just one outlier with a p-value. What I need is basically all the outliers along with their p-value of being outliers for each (`V,V1`) or on other words, all the candidates from `V2` along with their p-value of being an outlier to (`V,V1`).

Any ideas how can I change my code to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may work. The `dropout` function will do iterative looping to test for outliers. For each element you pass in, it will return 1 if the element is not an outliers, otherwise it will return the p-value < .05 for the outlier test.

```
library(outliers)
dropout<-function(x) {
    if(length(x)<2) return (1)
    vals <- rep.int(1, length(x))
    r <- chisq.out.test(x)
    while (r$p.value<.05 & sum(vals==1)>2) {
        if (grepl("lowest", r$alternative)) {
            d <- which.min(ifelse(vals==1,x, NA))
        } else {
            d <- which.max(ifelse(vals==1, x, NA))
        }
        vals[d] <- r$p.value
        r <- chisq.out.test(x[vals==1])
    }
    vals
}
```

With that helper function in place, we can now apply it to each of the sub-groups defined by `V`, `V1`. To do that, we use the `ave` function.

```
with(dd, ave(V3, V1, V2, FUN = dropout))
```

It appears your sample data has no outliers in any of the sub-groups given `chisq.out.test` definition of outliers.

And surely this iterative process is not statistically meaningful given the problem of resting for outliers in general and certainly with the multiple testing problem. Nevertheless, that discussion is for https://stats.stackexchange.com/, here we just focus on the code.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I update the function so it can return the outlier scores along with V,V1. But at the end, how can i get the corresponding row number for each outlier? so i can get which V2 is the outlier for each V, V1.

I call the function as follow :
`outliers <- d[, dropout(V3), list(V, V1)]

outliers <- merge(outliers, d[, list(max.ind=row[which.max(V3)]), list(V, V1)], by=c('V', 'V1'))`
but this would only give me the row index of the max, i want for each outlier the row index.

Comment: @ifreak `ave` returns the values in the same order it found them. So you can just add it back tot the data.frame, `dd$do <- with(dd, ave(V3, V1, V2, FUN = dropout))`.

Comment: now im having a weird error in the while (`missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`). do you have any idea why?

Comment: @ifreak That is insufficient information to diagnose the problem. My function worked on your test data above. If your real data is different somehow, I suggest you figure out how and see if that's causing the problem. I used the data.frame version of the data.