# Fill data.frame with missing columns

Tags: r

I have the following function taken from [R: iterative outliers detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23784843/r-iterative-outliers-detection) (this is an updated version):

```
dropout<-function(x) {
    outliers <- NULL
res <- NULL
    if(length(x)<2) return (1)
    vals <- rep.int(1, length(x))
    r <- chisq.out.test(x)
    while (r$p.value<.05 & sum(vals==1)>2) {
        if (grepl("highest",r$alternative)) {

            d <- which.max(ifelse(vals==1,x, NA))
            res <- rbind(list(as.numeric(strsplit(r$alternative," ")[[1]][3]),as.numeric(r$p.value)),fill=TRUE)

        } 
    else {
            d <- which.min(ifelse(vals==1, x, NA))

        }
        vals[d] <- r$p.value

        r <- chisq.out.test(x[vals==1])
    }

return(res)
}
```

The problem is that in each round it gives me some missing rows to fill in the data.frame

i want to fill `res` but in some iterations it contains missing values.

I used all possible things e.g `rbindlist, rbind.fill, rbind (with fill=TRUE)` but nothing is working.

When i do something like :

```
res <- c(res,as.numeric(strsplit(r$alternative," ")[[1]][3]),as.numeric(r$p.value))
```

it works but it creates 2 rows for each set of (V1,V2), one with the last column as `r$alternative`and the second row with the same first 2 columns but with the `p-value` in the last column instead.

Thats how I'm calling the function on data similar as the one in the mentioned question:

```
outliers <- d[, dropout(V3), list(V1, V2)]
```

and im getting always this error :   `j doesn't evaluate to the same number of columns for each group`

Comment: If your `d` a `data.table` rather than a `data.frame`. When do `res <- rbind(` are you trying to add rows? Because right now you're not rbinding to itself, you're just overwriting the value. Do you know why you are getting missing values? Perhaps you could include a dat aset that produces such a result?

Comment: yes im trying to add rows, but i want to neglect the empty ones.